# Como receber uma string e pelo switch fazer a verificação em C?

Tags: c, string, comparação, switch

Tenho que desenvolver um algoritmo que recebe o nome de um lugar, por exemplo, "Escola", e com base nisto, fazer uma verificação da *string* no `switch`, e caso seja "Escola", em seguida ele manda uma mensagem pro usuário sobre o que fazer, por exemplo, "Estudar".

**Código :**

```
 int main() {

    setlocale(LC_ALL,"portuguese");

    char lugar;

    printf("Digite o nome de um lugar : ");
    scanf("%c",&lugar);

    switch(lugar) {

    case 'Escola' :
    printf("Estudar");
    break;  


    }


 }
```

#### Erro :

> [Warning] character constant too long for its type
>
> [Error] switch quantity not an integer

Pelo o que eu vi, em C é muito diferente o conceito de *string*, e acaba sendo mais parecido com um *array* do que *string*, sendo vago o conceito

Comment: Isto não é possível, dá para fazer com `if` ou alguma solução bem mais complexa (*hash* por exemplo). Na verdade o código tem outros problemas, sequer está permitindo digitar a palavra.

Comment: Então, com if eu posso fazer isto ? Eu quero saber como, pois sequer realmente está permitindo digitar a palavra.

Comment: Mondial, você percebeu que está lendo somente um caracter? Você não está lendo uma string. Use `scanf("%s", lugar)` para ler uma string.

Comment: Obrigado Jefferson pelo esclarecimento, errei em alguns exercícios simplesmente por causa deste erro, bom, já corrigi aqui e me lembrarei no futuro sobre isto.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O código tem vários problemas. Precisa armazenar a *string*, precisa ler com o formato correto, precisa usar `if` e [`strcmp()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) para comparar *strings*.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char lugar[20]; //cria o array de caracteres para armazenar o texto
    printf("Digite o nome de um lugar: ");
    scanf("%20s", lugar); //não precisa da referência porque o array já é uma, precisa %s
    if (strcmp(lugar, "Escola") == 0) { //use a função para comparar todos os caracteres
        printf("\nEstudar");
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/ccjye7). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/kenwpktv-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/C/String/StringCompare.c).

Comment: Muito obrigado por ter mostrado o código e pela paciência por ter explicado ele. Sou novo em C e portanto cometo alguns erros bobos mesmo.

Answer (score 2):

Em C, você só pode por constantes escalares em um `switch`. Uma string é uma variável do tipo ponteiro, então teremos dificuldades usando exatamente esse método.

No Stackoverflow em inglês, quem respondeu [sugeriu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4014827/best-way-to-switch-on-a-string-in-c) que se use uma função de `hash` para poder usar o `switch` com a string; ou então usar o que chamaram de "escada" `if-else`.

A Wikipédia tem uma [entrada explicando funções de hash](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o_hash). Uma função de `hash` para uma string genérica pode ser definida assim (não vou fazer `null-safe`):

```
int hash_function(char *str) {
    int acc = 0;
    int peso = 1;
    int base = 256;
    int len = strlen(str);
    int modulus = 65000;

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        int char_at = str[i]; /* char é um número de 8 bits, enquanto que int é um número de 16 ou 32 bits, dependendo do compilador */
        acc = (acc*base + peso*char_at) % modulus;
        peso = (peso % 10) + 1; /* peso varia de 1 a 10 */
    }

    return acc;
}
```

Tendo a função de `hash` pré-determinada, já sabemos qual pode ser o valor de "Escola" e criando a macro `HASH_ESCOLA`:

```
int tratar_escola(char *lugar) {
    int hash_lugar = hash_function(lugar);
    switch (hash_lugar) {
    case HASH_ESCOLA:
        /* vamos checar se deu positivo verdadeiro? */
        if (strcmp(lugar, "Escola") == 0) {
            printf("Estudar\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Um algoritmo de `hash`/algoritmo de dispersão pode gerar colisões ([artigo da Wikipédia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabela_de_dispers%C3%A3o#Colis.C3.B5es)), que no caso é um outro objeto que retorna o mesmo valor do seu objeto desejado. Para evitar que dê uma colisão com um valor diferente de `Escola`, eu faço a comparação com a string original.