# Seletor de sexo em condicional if

Tags: c, string

Como faria nesse código pra pegar o **sexo** da pessoa e exibir no `printf()`?

Já vi muitas atividades em que na condição do `if`, se usava muito números e me bateu uma dúvida: *E se fosse com letras?*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  char sex[5], nome[200], f, m;

  printf("\n Digite o seu nome: " ); //pegar o nome da pessoa
  scanf(" %[^\n]s", &nome);

  printf("\n Digite seu sexo f ou m: "); //pegar o sexo da pessoa
  scanf("%s", &sex);

   if(sex == m)
    {
        printf(" bem vindo Senhor %s\n", nome); // se for homem
    }

   if (sex == f) 
    {
       printf(" Bem vinda Senhora %s\n", nome); // sefor mulher
    }

  else
   {
       printf("\n ERRO! \n");
   }

getchar();  
return 0;   
}
```

Comment: Você está recebendo o valor em uma variável "sex" e comparando com as variáveis "m" e "f" que não tem valor... Não precisa dessas duas variáveis. Compare com a string mesmo (sex == "f") e (sex == "m")

Comment: Definir variáveis é boa prática, mas se for para usar apenas neste contexto concordo com o @RodrigoTognin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neste caso só precisa uma caractere, não precisa mais que isto, conforme o código já mostra. Então não muda quase nada.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char sex, nome[200];
    printf("Digite o seu nome: ");
    scanf(" %[^\n]s", nome);
    printf("\nDigite seu sexo f ou m:"); //pegar o sexo da pessoa
    scanf("%c", &sex);
    if (sex == 'm' || sex == 'M') printf("Bem vindo Senhor %s\n", nome);
    else if (sex == 'f' || sex == 'F') printf("Bem vinda Senhora %s\n", nome);
    else printf("\n ERRO! \n");
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/vvGVc2). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/xtncejdv-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Char/Comparing.c).

Se quiser lidar com a palavra já tem uma [resposta sobre isto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/171109/101). [Outro exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/193124/101).

Comment: No Dev C++, o código funcionou, porém ao chegar em "Digite seu sexo f ou m:" . Ele já vai direto pra \n ERRO! \n;
Ficando assim:
Digite o seu nome: DIEGO
Digite seu sexo f ou m: // Essa parte não espera digitar f ou m
ERRO!

Comment: Mas no contexto da pergunta, sua resposta tira exatamente minha dúvida, apesar de que usando o switch case, seria mais inteligente de minha parte, mas como aprendizado, aprendi muita coisa hoje!

Comment: Dev C++ é uma bomba não recomendada por profissionais de C ou C++. Funcionar é diferente de estar certo. https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6eJF.jpg. tem até uma forma mais inteligente que isto, mas não é o `switch`.

Comment: Verdade sobre a imagem kkk.

Answer (score 0):

Primeiramente

```
if(sex == m)
    {
        printf(" bem vindo Senhor %s\n", nome); // se for homem
    }
```

Esse modo de comparação está errado. Pois a variável sex é um vetor de char, ou melhor, string como quiser chama-lo. Essa comparação == é para números (inteiros, float...) ou pode usar mas o m tem que estar assim 'm' e o sex tem que especificar a posição do vetor para referir o caractere propriamente dito; E seu m e f são variáveis e não possuem nada nelas, para usa-las seria necessário realizar um `scanf` de m ou f  ou atribuir um caractere f='f'...

Você pode usar strcmp para comparar por exemplo:

```
if(strcmp(sex,'m')==0) 
{
printf(" bem vindo Senhor %s\n", nome); // se for homem
 }
```

Requisitos:

Para usar o strcmp é necessário usar a biblioteca #include < string.h >  .

Para melhorar seu código:

`scanf("%s", &sex);`

Você poderia usar apenas um `getch()` ou `getche()` já que a entrada é apenas uma letra;

Requisitos: Para utilizar a função getch ou getche é necessário incluir a biblioteca conio.h no programa;

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer

```
char sex;
```

Quando for pegar o valor use `scanf("%c",&sex)` ou `scanf("%s",&sex)` e para comparar você usa `if(sex == 'm')` use aspas simples pois é somente um caractere.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char sex;
    printf("Digite seu sexo f ou m:");
    scanf("%c", &sex);

    if (sex == 'm') printf("Masculino");
}
```