# Usando a função switch em C++

Tags: c, c++, switch

A função `switch` e não sei oque estou fazendo de errado quero colocar o nome `marcos` ai aparecer "marcos e legal" e se colocar `murilo` "murilo e bacana". Estou fazendo assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
int main(void)
 {
  char marcos;
  printf("Digite um nome e veja? ");
  scanf("%s",&nome);
  switch (nome) 
  { 
    case 'marcos' : 
    printf("Marcos e legal");
    break;
    case 'murilo':
    printf("Murilo e bacana");
    break;
    default: 
    printf("errado");

     getch();
    return 0;
}

  }
```

Comment: Clique em [edit], selecione o bloco de código e aperte `control+K` pra formatar, ou use o botão `{ }` da barra de formatação. Seria bom aproveitar a edição e descrever melhor o que aconteceu de errado com sua tentativa.

Comment: @FábioMorais se os `case`s são numéricos não pode ser duplicata desta.

Comment: "switch" não é uma função, é um comando

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 3):

Não é possível usar *strings*  no `case`, lá só pode usar tipos simples como números e caracteres individuais (que não deixam de ser números). Se precisa fazer com *string* tem que usar [`if` e `strcmp()`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/193128/101) mesmo. Em C++ pode usar o `==` em um tipo `string` próprio dele.

Você pode entender [Como funciona o switch por baixo dos panos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/176675/101).

E se fosse usar *string* teria que ser com aspas duplas (`"`). Aspas simples (`'`) é apenas para caractere único que não deixa de ser um tipo numérico, mas que pode ser impresso como caractere. A *string* é só uma sequência desses caracteres terminado com um [nulo (`\0`)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177619/101).

Além disso a variável `nome` não foi declarada, foi uma outra sem sentido que não foi usada. E ela deveria ser declarada como *array* ou fazer alocação dinâmica que é muito avançado.

E nunca use `conio.h`.